# React Cyclic dependency importing named export

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 containers, both import a component called `PageHeader` this is a functional component and is imported / exported as like so....

( this happens with any component I import, not just PageHeader )

**components/PageHeader/PageHeader.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import './PageHeader.sass';

const PageHeader = ({ title, description, image }) => (
  <div className="section is-paddingless is-hidden-touch">
    <div className="header header__desktop" style={{ backgroundImage: `url('${image}')` }}>
      <h3 className="is-size-3 has-text-weight-semibold">{title}</h3>
      <h5>{description}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
);

PageHeader.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  description: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  image: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default PageHeader;
```

**components/PageHeader/index.js**

```
import PageHeader from './PageHeader';
export default PageHeader;
```

In the root of my components folder I then have....

**components/index.js**

```
......
export { default as PageHeader } from './PageHeader';
......
```

This allows me to import components into a container like so....

```
import { DelayedComponent, Loading, Page, PageHeader, ClientList, RecentlyViewed, ClientFilter } from '../../components';
```

When I only had 1 container, this was working fine, I have now introduced a second container, this is essentially a second page.

My Containers are as follows....

**containers/Clients/Clients.jsx**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { DelayedComponent, Loading, Page, PageHeader, ClientList, RecentlyViewed, ClientFilter } from '../../components';

import headerImage from '../../assets/images/client-search-banner.jpg';

class Clients extends Component {
  state = { selector: 'ALL' };

  static propTypes = {
    fetchClientListAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    selectClientAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    clients: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchClientListAction();
  }

  onClientSelect = client => this.props.selectClientAction(client);

  onFilterTenantList = selector => this.setState({ selector });

  render() {
    const { isLoading, clients } = this.props;
    const { selector } = this.state;

    if (isLoading)
      return (
        <DelayedComponent>
          <Loading />
        </DelayedComponent>
      );

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <PageHeader
          title="Choose a client"
          description="Bacon ipsum dolor amet ribeye biltong tongue, pig brisket venison fatback pork bacon kielbasa burgdoggen salami strip steak."
          image={headerImage}
        />
        <Page>
          <Page.Columns>
            <Page.Column modifiers="is-paddingless">
              <ClientFilter clients={clients} selector={selector} filterByLetter={this.onFilterTenantList} />
            </Page.Column>
          </Page.Columns>
          <Page.Columns modifiers="is-multiline">
            <Page.Column modifiers="is-two-thirds">
              <ClientList clients={clients} selector={selector} onClientSelect={this.onClientSelect} />
            </Page.Column>
            <Page.Column modifiers="is-one-third">
              <RecentlyViewed />
            </Page.Column>
          </Page.Columns>
        </Page>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Clients;
```

**containers/EmployeeSearch/EmployeeSearch.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { PageHeader } from '../../components';

import headerImage from '../../assets/images/client-search-banner.jpg';

class EmployeeSearch extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
             <PageHeader
          title="Search"
          description="Bacon ipsum dolor amet ribeye biltong tongue, pig brisket venison fatback pork bacon kielbasa burgdoggen salami strip steak."
          image={headerImage}
        />
    );
  }
}

export default EmployeeSearch;
```

Doing this causes Webpack crash with the following error...

```
/Users/xxxxx/Code/xxxxx/search-webapp/node_modules/toposort/index.js:29
      throw new Error('Cyclic dependency: '+JSON.stringify(node))
                                                 ^

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at visit (/Users/xxxxx/Code/xxxxx/search-webapp/node_modules/toposort/index.js:29:50)
    at visit (/Users/xxxxx/Code/xxxxx/search-webapp/node_modules/toposort/index.js:47:9)
    at visit (/Users/xxxxx/Code/xxxxx/search-webapp/node_modules/toposort/index.js:47:9)
    at Function.toposort [as array] (/Users/xxxxx/Code/xxxxx/search-webapp/node_modules/toposort/index.js:22:22)
    at Object.module.exports.dependency (/Users/xxxxx/Code/xxxxx/search-webapp/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/chunksorter.js:50:35)
    at HtmlWebpackPlugin.sortChunks (/Users/xxxxx/Code/xxxxx/search-webapp/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/index.js:364:35)
    at /Users/xxxxx/Code/xxxxx/search-webapp/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/index.js:113:21
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/xxxxx/Code/xxxxx/search-webapp/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (/Users/xxxxx/Code/xxxxx/search-webapp/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:35:21)
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
```

However, if I change the import in `EmployeeSearch.jsx` so it looks like this....

```
import PageHeader from '../../components/PageHeader';
```

It works.

I am at a complete loss and would love some input as to why / how this happening and how I can fix this without adding multiple import statements for components.

My Containers are rendered as follows....

```
import React from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Loading from './components/Loading';

const AsyncRoute = loader =>
  Loadable({
    loader,
    loading: Loading,
    delay: 300,
  });

const Clients = AsyncRoute(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "clients" */ './containers/Clients'));
const EmployeeSearch = AsyncRoute(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "employee-search" */ './containers/EmployeeSearch'));

const Routes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Clients} />
    <Route path="/employee-search/:client" component={EmployeeSearch} />
  </Switch>
);

export default Routes;
```

Comment: doesn your index.js file import EmployeeSearch

Comment: I've updated my question with how my containers are rendered

Comment: What i wanted to know is whether `components/index.js` imports `containers/EmployeeSearch/EmployeeSearch.jsx`

Comment: Ah, sorry, no it does not, it only imports the contents of the Components folder

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had included App within my components index.js file.

My routes are wrapped in App, so that was my circular dependancy.